# meaning of "proceed to"

Tags: meaning

Per [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proceed?q=proceeded), "proceed to" means

> to do something after you have done something else

Consider these

> Alice sat down and **proceeded to tell** bob about her skiing holiday.
>
> Alice sat down and **told** bob about her skiing holiday.
>
> Alice sat down and **began to tell** bob about her skiing holiday.

Is there any difference between them in meaning?

Does the subject of "have done something else" have to be Alice?

Comment: I think your first example has the closest meaning to ***"went on to tell Bob ( which means that they probably had some other discussion between them before her sitting down)"***, whereas the third example means that ***" she got herself telling Bob ....... after she had sat down "***.

Comment: Wound't your first line mean your Camblidge's "to start or continue an action or process:"?